# Julia can't find package even if it's in Project.toml deps section

Tags: julia, pyproject.toml

I have a problem when testing my Julia (v1.8.1) project: if I run the "runtest.jl" file (using Visual Studio Code) everything is ok, but when I try to run it in Julia REPL something goes wrong:

```
julia> using Pkg; Pkg.activate(normpath(@__DIR__)); Pkg.test()
    Activating project at `~/path/to/project`
     Testing Myproject
      Status `/tmp/jl_sEwRcU/Project.toml`
  [38da103c] muproject v1.2.1 `~/path/to/project`
  [8dfed614] Test `@stdlib/Test`
      Status `/tmp/jl_sEwRcU/Manifest.toml`
  [a4c015fc] ANSIColoredPrinters v0.0.1
  [621f4979] AbstractFFTs v1.3.1
  ...
     Testing Running tests...
ERROR: LoadError: ArgumentError: Package LinearAlgebra not found in current path.
- Run `import Pkg; Pkg.add("LinearAlgebra")` to install the LinearAlgebra package.
Stacktrace:
...
in expression starting at /path/to/project/test/runtests.jl:20
```

where in `runtests.jl`:20 there's:

```
19    using Mymodule
20    using Test, LinearAlgebra, StaticArrays
```

but doing `Pkg.satus()`, the `LinearAlgebra` package results to be installed in the virtual ambient:

```
julia> Pkg.status()
Project myprog v0.1.0
...
  [37e2e46d] LinearAlgebra
...
```

and I get a specular result with `StaticArrays` if in `runtests.jl`:20 I write:

```
19    using Mymodule
20    using Test, StaticArrays, LinearAlgebra
```

Note: both packages are in the dependencies Project.toml section.

If I do as suggested, there are no changes and `Pkg.test()` fails again:

```
julia> import Pkg; Pkg.add("StaticArrays")
    Updating registry at `~/.julia/registries/General.toml`
   Resolving package versions...
  No Changes to `~/path/to/project/Project.toml`
  No Changes to `~/path/to/project/Manifest.toml`
```

Has anyone a solution or a suggestion?

Comment: What is the result of adding the package using ']add LinearAlgebra '? Have you tried ']resolve' ?

Answer (score 0):

`Pkg.test()` runs the tests in a separate environment distinct from that of the project itself. Since you want to use `LinearAlgebra` and `StaticArrays` from within test code, you have to add the packages to this test environment too.

Currently, do you have a `Project.toml` file under the `test/` directory? If so, switch to that environment (`]activate ~/path/to/project/test`), `]add LinearAlgebra StaticArrays` there, switch back to the project environment (`]activate ..`), and run `Pkg.test()` now.